# How do I get HTML generated by skel/jQuery to detect angularJS directives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to adapt a cool template I found (http://templated.co/monochromed) into an AngularJS single-page app. The template has a responsive UI that accommodates mobile devices really well, but it uses skel and jQuery. I'm not too familiar with jQuery, but I'm having an issue where the html it generates for mobile doesn't pick up ng-click directives. Is getting an angular directive to work here even possible?

My navbar:

```
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-class="{active: tab === 'home'}"><a ng-click="tab = 'home'" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{active: tab === 'about_us'}"><a ng-click="tab = 'about_us'" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{active: tab === 'blog'}"><a ng-click="tab = 'blog'" href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{active: tab === 'events'}"><a ng-click="tab = 'events'" href="#">Events</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{active: tab === 'podcast'}"><a ng-click="tab = 'podcast'" href="#">Podcast</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

What skel produces for a mobile device:

```
<nav>
<a class="link depth-0" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; display: block; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <span class="indent-0"></span>Home
</a>
<a class="link depth-0" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; display: block; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <span class="indent-0"></span>About Us
</a>
<a class="link depth-0" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; display: block; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <span class="indent-0"></span>Blog
</a>
<a class="link depth-0" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; display: block; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <span class="indent-0"></span>Events
</a>
<a class="link depth-0" href="#" style="cursor: pointer; display: block; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">
    <span class="indent-0"></span>Podcast
</a>
</nav>
```

The relevant piece of skel.init:

```
navPanel: {
            breakpoints: 'mobile',
            position: 'left',
            style: 'reveal',
            size: '80%',
            html: '<div data-action="navList" data-args="nav"></div>'
        }
```

Angular Controller:

```
angular.module('mainApp',[])
.controller('navCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.tab = 'home';
    $scope.pages = {
        home: {
            url: "home.html"
        },
        about_us: {
            url: "about_us.html"
        },
        blog: {
            url: "blog.html"
        },
        events: {
            url: "events.html"
        },
        podcast: {
            url: "podcast.html"
        }
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Where is your module/controller code?

Comment: Added the controller, but I don't think it has anything to do with ng-click not showing up.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question properly. It seems more like a skel issue rather than Angular. Did you try any other of the directive prefixes? `data-ng-click, ng:click, ng_click, x-ng-click`?

Comment: I found the part of skel responsible. It's programmatically generating the mobile html and only looking at the href. I actually edited the source code to have it generate the ng-click html as well, but whatever it does isn't detected by angular. I probably need to set up ng-route so that the href on it's own is sufficient.

Comment: I would recommend then adding an answer to your question so people will know what to do in the future! :-)